# Stopping/muting audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, audio

How would I be able to pause the following audio object when a link with the class "iFrame" is clicked?

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="140" height="20">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="movie" value="../flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf">
<param name="FlashVars" value="configxml=../flash/config.xml&amp;mp3=../audio/intro/intro_08_background_07.mp3">
<p>Flash Audio Player</p>
</object>
```

I need to write the code in javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Provided it's your own .swf and that you can recompile it, I'd say you need to expose the players pause method using ExternalInterface. If you haven't done it before, have a look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=19_External_Interface_04.html

Once you've done that you just add an event listener to the HTML link and assign a function to be triggered when the user clicks. This function calls the exposed flash function to pause.

```
theLink.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    //call the exposed flash pause function
    swfObject.theExposedFunction();
});
```

Makes sense?